# Porting C# reflection code to Metro-Ui

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to port an existing C# class (a generic factory) that uses reflection, but I can't get this piece of code to compile:

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TProduct)).GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (!typeof(TProduct).IsAssignableFrom(type) || type == typeof(TProduct))
...
```

I tried looking at the [Reflection in the .NET Framework for Windows Metro Style Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#reflection) and [Assembly Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where I found an example that didn't compile because of the "using System.Security.Permissions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like the first page you linked to says, you need to use `TypeInfo` instead of `Type`. There are also other changes, for example, `Assembly` has a `DefinedTypes` property instead of `GetTypes()` method. The modified code could look like this:

```
var tProductType = typeof(TProduct).GetTypeInfo();
var types = tProductType.Assembly.DefinedTypes; // or .ExportedTypes
foreach (var type in types)
{
    if (!tProductType.IsAssignableFrom(type) || type == tProductType)
    { }
}
```