# Get all classes in a referenced assembly for Windows 8.1 Universal app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, .net-assembly

I have a project that I am moving from Windows Phone 8 to Universal Windows 8.1.

### Scenario

In the Solution I have multiple assemblies that implements interfaces that are defined in common assembly (but not all in each, they vary), but all implements or extends the interface `IResolver`.

I used reflection in my "main" project/assembly to register the classes that are in the referenced assemblies by passing it an instance of an implementation of the `IResolver` (interface) of that assembly.

### The code

```
using System.Reflection;
...
public void Register(IResolver resolver)
{
   foreach (Type classType in resolver.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes())
   {
      // Register the class type with the ioc container
   }
}
```

And it worked like a charm :-)

### The problem

`System.Type` does not contain a definition for `Assembly` and no extension method `Assembly` accepting a first argument of type `System.Type` could be found

In the documentation of [Type.Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx) it states:

*Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8*

Thus *not supported* in Windows 8.1, but even if it is in the Windows Phone 8.1 project, still says does not contain a definition for `Assembly`.

And if that's not enough, the class `Assemly` does not implement the method `GetTypes()`

### The question

How do I get all of the classes defined in a referenced assembly for Universal App from an instance of an interface?

Any suggestions or alternatives?

### Things that don't work

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

Error: `System.Reflection.Assembly` does not contain a definition for `GetExecutingAssembly`

Comment: I think that's the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680757/porting-c-sharp-reflection-code-to-metro-ui

Comment: Thanks @KooKiz . Yeah, I see it is sort of the same. I solved it anyway, dam so much time waisted :P hehehe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this was annoying...

`GetType().GetTypeInfo()`

```
public void Register(IResolver resolver)
{
   foreach (Type classType in resolver.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetExportedTypes())
   {
      // Register the class type with the ioc container
   }
}
```